# Dealing with adb devices

Tags: adb

I recently started using the adb command line utility tool and what I'm trying to do is to extract all of the images from a folder on my android device.
I've tried the command below with no success.

```
 adb pull /data/media/0/Pictures/Screenshots/*.png   /root/Desktop
```

I've also tried a specific image

```
 adb pull '/data/media/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2017-12-15-04-51-19.png'
```

every time i run the adb pull command i seem to get the error

```
 adb: error: remote object '/root/data/media/0/Pictures does not exist'
```

adb is case sensitive, so i made sure i was accurate before proceeding with the above commands

update: I have tried the adb push command but it outputs the error code

```
 adb: error: failed to copy : Read-only file system
```

i failed to mention in the above example of pulling a file from my adb device, i was successful in pulling 5 wifi files, but the picture extractions remain unknown... at this point i have narrowed it down to the media folder, it will extract the data, but anything past it gets lost, file not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "adb push", copy a file from your host to device to that location.

You can also verify the location(path) by using "adb shell" command. After executing "adb shell", you will get a shell prompt of your device and you can verify the location in it.

If "adb shell" or "adb psuh" doesn't work then *make sure your device is connected to host properly and you gave the permission.*

You can restart the adb by using "adb kill-server && adb start-server" command.

Answer (score 0):

adb: error: remote object '/root/data/media/0/Pictures does not exist'

You forgot a trial slash behind 'Pictures'